# Cannot understand why getting "type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4. 
I am getting **type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'** error although I am implementing `IDisposable` so I am not sure where I am making the mistake. Please check and let me know.

I have a class named `MyDatabaseContext` which contains `DbConnection`; it implements `IDisposable` :

```
public abstract class MyDatabaseContext : IDisposable
{
   private string _dataProvider;
   private string _connectionString;
   private DbConnection _dbConnection;

   public MyDatabaseContext(string dataProvider, string connectionString)
   {
      _dataProvider = dataProvider;
      _connectionString = connectionString;
   }

   public void OpenConnection()
   {
      DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_dataProvider);
      _dbConnection = dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
      _dbConnection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
      _dbConnection.Open();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      if (_dbConnection != null)
      {
         if (_dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
         {
            _dbConnection.Close();
         }
         _dbConnection.Dispose();
         _dbConnection = null;
      }
   }
}
```

Now I have a class `EmployeeDatabaseContext` which inherit from `MyDatabaseContext`. In it I have a method **test()** where I am calling the parent class's **OpenConnection()** method inside `using` block.

```
public class EmployeeDatabaseContext : MyDatabaseContext
{
   public EmployeeDatabaseContext(string dataProvider, string connectionString)
            : base(dataProvider, connectionString)
   {
   }

   public void test()
   {
      using (OpenConnection())
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Problem is I am getting error when I build. Error is in `EmployeeDatabaseContext` class in **test()** method on the `using` block. The error is

> 'void': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible
>   to 'System.IDisposable'

But the parent class `MyDatabaseContext` is implementing `IDisposable` so I dont know why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: `OpenConnection()` returns void. To use it in a using statement, it needs to return an object that implements IDisposable. It doesn't matter what the class owing the method implements. The using statement doesn't go off looking for something nearby to dispose. It disposes exactly what you give it, and you're not giving it anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenConnection()` returns void. To use it in a using statement, it needs to return an object that implements IDisposable. It doesn't matter what the class owing the method implements. The using statement doesn't go off looking for something nearby to dispose. It disposes exactly what you give it, and you're not giving it anything.

So:

```
public MyDatabaseContext(string dataProvider, string connectionString)
{
    _dataProvider = dataProvider;
    _connectionString = connectionString;

    OpenConnection();
}
```

But let `OpenConnection()` not be public, as you don't want interlopers calling it redundantly:

```
protected void OpenConnection()
{
    // ...
}
```

You're correctly calling the base constructor in EmployeeDatabaseContext's constructor, so that's fine.

And here's how you use it in a using statement:

```
public void test()
{
    using (var ctxt = new EmployeeDatabaseContext(someProviderString, someConnString))
    {
        //  Do stuff with ctxt
        //  ctxt.Dispose() will be called when control exits this block. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of `using` as much more intelligent than what it is. Now I am thinking what is the point of having _dbConnection in the parent class.

Comment: @srh If you're going to have multiple child classes that'll each need one, you're right to declare it once in the parent. For subclasses to make use of it, you could expose it in the base class via a public or protected property.